# Retrieve entire sqlite table in blackberry

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

Is it possible to fetch the entire database table, rows and columns into a form in blackberry?
I have been able to retrieve values from records into a richtextfield but i want to retrieve them on to textboxes so that individual columns and rows can be updated from the form.
Heres the code i've been working on

```
 //Retrieve data
     try
    {
      add(new RichTextField("Attempting to retrieve data from " + 
                                       "database1.db on the SDCard."));

     Statement st = db.createStatement("SELECT name,email FROM DirectoryItems");

     st.prepare();

     Cursor c = st.getCursor();

     Row r;
     int i = 0;

     while(c.next()) 
     {

     r = c.getRow();
     i++;
  add(new RichTextField(i + ".Name = " + r.getString(0) +
                                              " , " +
      "Email = " + r.getString(1))); //+
      //  " , " +
      //"Phone = " + r.getInteger(1)));
     }

     if (i==0)
    {
    add(new RichTextField("No data in the DirectoryItems table."));
    }
    st.close();
   db.close();
    }
  catch( Exception e ) 
   {         
    System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: Closing db and statement inside try block is leading to errors with database in future calls

Comment: ok dat problem can be sorted.But the issue i am trying to point out is that i want to retrieve them onto a textfield.Any idea about that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to give the complete solutions - it requires testing, running and won't be so helpful in terms of the education.

I don't see any problems to do that. Any row in table has row id column. Any `Field` in blackberry ui has methods `setCookie`, `getCookie`, `isDirty`. You could set also `FocusListener` for every `Field` (I don't like to call save to database on every change event, but doing this on focus leaving sound reasonable).

So the idea is that you fetch your data and put it to `EditFields` (one field per value, so there will be two fields for name and email). You save to cookie for field row id and column name. And on every focus leave event you check if field is dirty and safely save changed data in case of true.

This is quite rough idea and it sounds way away from OOP (it means hard to reuse or extend in future). But it should work.

Comment: I am unsure about any concept of cookies being used in a blackberry development.Though i wouldnt mind researching more on dis.Thanks for the reply.